# ModuleNotFoundError: mysql.connector issue in Google Cloud VM

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to connect to a `MySQL` database using `python3` in Google Cloud VM instance which has `Linux bk1-1 4.19.0-18-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux` system.

First, I installed `mysql-connector-python` using:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
# Successfully installed mysql-connector-python-8.0.28
```

However, when I try to `import mysql.connector`, I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package
```

I tried the previous steps on my laptop which have the system `Linux pop-os 5.15.23-76051523-generic #202202110435~1644952300~21.10~96763f1 SMP Tue Feb 15 19:52:40 U x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and it worked for me.

Python version in google cloud: `Python 3.7.3`
Python version in my laptop: `Python 3.9.7`

I tried also:

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

I got the same issue

Comment: how are you running your code on the VM? It might be you're not using the same python as the one you installed thhe my-sql package on... Note, you should actually use a `virtualenv` to prevent this

Comment: I use `screen` to run my code thru `ssh`. And Yes, I am using `virtualenv`

Comment: what does `pip freeze` show?

Comment: `mysql-connector-python-rf==2.2.2` with mysql-connector-python-rf

Comment: `mysql-connector-python==8.0.28` with mysql-connector-python

Comment: I had a file named `mysql.py` which caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for my issue and it is a very stupid thing. There was a file in the directory named `mysql.py` which caused confusion.

I just renamed it and solved it!!